# VBA Excel RadioButton does not work properly until i delete another RadioButton and undo

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, groupbox

I am currently working on Option-buttons in VBA. I want to add a Group-box, in which there are 6 Option-buttons (all connected to a fixed cell somewhere). Only at max one of those Option-buttons shall be able to be active.

It should look like this:

[image: It should look like this.]

I want to create this with a VBA macro. The problem is, that when I create this, Button-1 and Button-6 are connected. If I select one, I select both. All other Radio-buttons are not like this, and can be clicked separately.

Additionally, if I manually delete one of those Radio-buttons, and click Ctrl+Y, everything works just fine.. then all 6 buttons can be selected separately.

Do you have any idea what I could do, such I do not have to first delete one button and undo this to make this work properly?

*Edit: Code added*

```
Sub ButtonsInABox()
    ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Delete
    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Delete
startcell = Array(1, 1)

        Add_GroupBox Array(startcell(0), startcell(1))
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0), startcell(1)), "Button-1", "A11"
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0), startcell(1) + 1), "Button-2", "A11"
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0), startcell(1) + 2), "Button-3", "A11"
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0) + 1, startcell(1)), "Button-4", "A11"
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0) + 1, startcell(1) + 1), "Button-5", "A11"
            Add_RadioButton Array(startcell(0) + 1, startcell(1) + 2), "Button-6", "A11"

End Sub


Sub Add_RadioButton(startcell, ButtonName, corresponding_cell)
   a = startcell(0)
   b = startcell(1)
   xx = Cells(a, b).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

   ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(Range(xx).Left, Range(xx).Top, Range(xx).Width * 1, 4).Select
   With Selection
    .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.65, msoFalse
    .Characters.Text = ButtonName
    .LinkedCell = corresponding_cell
    .Display3DShading = True
    End With

End Sub


Sub Add_GroupBox(startcell)
    a = startcell(0)
    b = startcell(1)
    xx = Cells(a, b).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)


    ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Add(Range(xx).Left, Range(xx).Top, Range(xx).Width * 3, Range(xx).Height * 2).Select

    Selection.Characters.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by sharing the code?

Comment: Thank you, I have now added a Code, which reproduces my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing the issue because of the line

```
ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Add(Range(xx).Left, Range(xx).Top, _
Range(xx).Width * 3, Range(xx).Height * 2).Select
```

If you change it to

```
ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Add(Range(xx).Left, Range(xx).Top, _
Range(xx).Width * 3.5, Range(xx).Height * 2.5).Select
```

It will work. Seems like Excel is getting confused whether the object is inside the group or not. Better to include extra margins around the option buttons.

By the way, avoid using `.Select`. Work with object directly as shown in the example below.

---

### Alternative

If you want there is one more way to achieve what you want. This method doesn't use a `GroupBox`. It groups the controls together. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Variant
    Dim ShpGroup As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startcell As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim CellAddr As String
    Dim Shapenames As String
    Dim ShpAr(1 To 6) As Variant

    Set ws = Sheet1

    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp

    k = 1

    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 3
            CellAddr = Cells(i, j).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            Set shp = ws.OptionButtons.Add(Range(CellAddr).Left, Range(CellAddr).Top, Range(CellAddr).Width, 4)

            With shp
                .Name = "Button " & k
                .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.65, msoFalse
                .Characters.Text = "Button " & k
                .LinkedCell = "A11"
                .Display3DShading = True
            End With

            '~~> Store the shape name in an array
            ShpAr(k) = "Button " & k
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Set ShpGroup = ws.Shapes.Range(ShpAr).Group
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested both, both do work. For my current project i have several GroupBoxes adjacent to each other, so increasing the size of all does not work without disturbing the design. The second solution however allows not to use GroupBoxes at all, which is perfect!
Thank you

Comment: I have updated the code. Instead of hardcoding the shape names in the array, I have made it dynamic :)

Comment: Ah wait, if I want to have two oft those boxes with some Radio-buttons, and I want to group them separately, they group together.

Comment: Yes you group them separately using separate loops